# SVD: How to scale singular values after rotating U and V (Matlab)

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, bootstrap-sampling

I am very new to linear algebra...

I construct a rectangular matrix **A1** from some sampled data which is m x n where m > n

```
[U1, S1, V1] = svd(A1)
```

If I then construct a new matrix **A2** (also m x n, m > n) using resampling for e.g. bootstrapping of the original data I can then calculate a new SVD

```
[U2, S2, V2] = svd(A2)
```

Because of this that I read:

> "Note that the decomposition of the resampled matrix is not guaranteed
>   to produce a comparable set of latent variables, because both permutation and bootstrap resampling could induce arbitrary axis rotation
>   (i.e.  a change in the order of the latent variables) and/or axis
>   reflection (i.e. a sign change for the weights)"

...I believe I need to correct using rotation using the original as a target?

```
[~, Q] = rotatefactors(U2, 'Method', 'procrustes', 'Target', U1, 'Type', 'orthogonal')
```

I want to then rotate my **U2** and **V2** matrices (is this the right way?):

```
U2r = U2 * S2 * Q;
V2r = V2 * S2 * Q;
```

- however because the matrices **A1** and **A2** are not square, this fails in Matlab.

Finally, I want to calculate the new singular values **S2r** (is this necessary??) 
How do I scale them appropriately given that I have rotated **U2** and **V2**?

Is this possible or have I completely misunderstood the process??

Thanks for any help, please bear in mind that I am a total beginner.

Answer (score 1):

We have but a fragment of information, so the answer may suffer limited applicability.

In general, the singular value decomposition provides an orthonormal basis to the domain $(\mathbf{V})$ and the codomain $(\mathbf{U})$. Additionally, the spaces are *aligned* by the SVD. The relative rotations are sacred. You can't just change one.

In general
$$
 \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^* \ne
 \mathbf{R}(\theta) \, \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma  \, \left( \mathbf{R}(\theta) \mathbf{V} \, \right)^{*}
$$